# How to extract BM25 score from Solr

Tags: solr

for an document auto-tagging system we would like to apply `tags` based on `Solrs BM25` measure.

Our algorithm should perform like this:

- indexed documents with applied tags already stored in Solr
- new documents without tags are posted => apply tags based on the nearest neighbor of this document (afaik document with best BM25)

So my questions:

1. Is this feasible? Can I extract the BM25-score out of Solr? This could require first indexing a document get the nearest neighbor and his tags and then deleting the new doc and re-index with applied tags from nearest neighbor
2. Is this in general a good Idea to do so?

Comment: There is already a KNN classifier available in the update chain for Solr - that might do what you want without going through the extra hoops: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrClassification

Comment: Awesome! Thank you I will dig into that.